# Is WSO2 Identity Server supporting OpenId Connect Discovery

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I am working with WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0 and tried a client library (oxRay) to utilize its OpenID Connect capabilities.
However, it seems that the request to the discovery URL `https://myserver/.well-known/openid-configuration` doesn't return anything reasonable. So the OIDC client fails to work properly.
Is Identity Server supporting OIDC discovery or did I miss something in the configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSO2 Identity Server does not support OIDC Discovery at the current releases.

Comment: Does WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0 support for the OIDC Discovery.

Comment: I'm working with 5.2 now and looks like it still does not support it.

Comment: It supports 5.3 onwards

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 Identity Server 5.3.0 does support OpenID Connect Discovery.

From the [release notes](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/About+this+Release) (emphasis mine):

> OAuth 2.0/Open ID Connect Enhancements:
>
> - Open ID Connect Dynamic Client Registration. For more information, see OpenID Connect Dynamic Client Registration.
> - OAuth 2.0 Token Introspection. For more information, see Invoke the OAuth Introspection Endpoint.
> - **Open ID Connect Discovery support**. For more information, see the Open ID Connect specification.

However, I do seem to have run into an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42060839/3558960) when trying to use it.